# Repeating reminders for upcoming events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, is it possible to set up repeating reminders for upcoming deadlines and events? I want to set an hourly alarm that will show the amount of time remaining until the next calendar event, but I haven't yet found a feature like this.

For example, if my next deadline was a project that needed to be finished by February 30, 2013, I would want to receive an email notification every hour that showed the number of days remaining until the deadline.

Comment: I could simply set a repeating event that ran from the present time until the deadline, and then send email notifications for that event. However, that would require me to create repeating events for every single deadline, which would be tedious.

Comment: There is a Firefox extension called ReminderFox that displays reminders for upcoming events, although it does not sync with Google Calendar, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid creating so many events, you should take advantage of the built-in rule engine of the iCalendar standard ([RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)) supported by Google Calendar.

The below should work in a fully iCalendar compliant calendar but I do not believe that Google Calendar would support it

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:pyICSParser
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130224T190000
DTEND:20130228T235959
DTSTAMP:20130205T114500
UID:WA_40871.ics
SUMMARY:Project
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130226T210000Z
REPEAT:120
DURATION:PT1H
ACTION:EMAIL
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Which file type is shown here?

Comment: It's possible to import events from iCalendar and CSV files. http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37118

Comment: @AndersonGreen: That should be a `.ics` file, I believe.

Comment: this is indeed an icalendar file (*.ics)

Comment: In this case, what would this reminder do?

Comment: from the 26/feb (see TRIGGER) it will every hours (see duration) for 120 times (see repeat) send an email (see action) with a title of Reminder (see Description)

Comment: Does this actually work on Google Calendar? Has anyone tried it?